# CMake not detecting CXX but detecting CPP files

Tags: c++, cmake, detect

I'm trying to learn CMake from http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake_tutorial.html and running into trouble with the first step itself of running a simple file tutorial.cpp.

The issue is that when I have this command in my CMakeLists.txt file

```
add_executable(Tutorial tutorial.cpp)
```

it builds fine.

However, when I change it to

```
add_executable(Tutorial tutorial.cxx)
```

It gives the following error

```
-- Configuring done
CMake Error at src/CMakeLists.txt:6 (add_executable):
  Cannot find source file:

    tutorial.cxx

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp
  .hxx .in .txx


-- Build files have been written to: /home/vaisagh/workspace/Test/build
```

My directory structure is like this:

```
.
├── build
├── CMakeLists.txt
└── src
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    └── tutorial.cpp

2 directories, 3 files
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
#Specify the version being used aswell as the language
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11)
#Name your project here
project(Tutorial)
add_subdirectory(src)
```

src/CMakeLists.txt

```
#Specify the version being used aswell as the language
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11)
add_executable(Tutorial tutorial.cxx)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Tried extensions .c .C...` Indicates that CMake tried to search for `tutorial.cxx.c`, `tutorial.cxx.C`, etc.

The source filename given to `add_executable` must match the actual filename on disc.

1. Rename `tutorial.cpp` to `tutorial.cxx` -or-
2. Change `add_executable(Tutorial tutorial.cxx)` to `add_executable(Tutorial tutorial.cpp)`

Comment: Thanks! What if use a third idea? Changing the line to add_executable(Tutorial tutorial) This builds the project fine. But i'm not sure if there's some problems with this.

Comment: I can imagine an issue if you accidentally created a `tutorial.c` file in that directory, then your build will either succeed or fail dependant on the suffix search order of CMake.